# Devise token encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise with the Token Authenticatable module. If I look at the data stored in the database, I see that even though the password is encrypted, the access token is not.

Isn't this a major security concern, since if a hacker ever got ahold of the database info, they would have the raw, completely functional access token, comparable to storing an unhashed password?

Answer (score 0):

Security and convenience usually go on opposites sides. **It is less secure, but there are ways to mitigate this** (reducing convenience, of course). You could expire the token often (using `expire_auth_token_on_timeout` or periodically reset all tokens.

If your DB is compromised, you have bigger problems! Passwords are usually shared between services by users, so a leaked password is, by far, worst than a leaked auth_token.

*Why are they not encrypted?*

Passwords are stored in the user's mind, auth_tokens are generated and they will have to be stored somewhere (client-side) in order to be submitted and compared with the encrypted auth_token. A new token will have to be generated every time the user signs in with their "normal" credentials.

Performance might be an issue too. BCrypt is slow and doing this comparison on every request might present an issue.

---

*I couldn't find a "official" answer in the documentation or by one of the developers, so the answer provided is based on my experience and opinion.*